# ResposiveNess of div with multiple content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I am using Bootstrap 4. My HTML code is like below.

```
<div class="font-weight-bold col-12">
  <span>Filter :</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Before decrease the browser size my output is like below

[image]

After decrease the browser size my output is like below

[image]

How can I keep both elements in the same line after I decrease the browser size?

Comment: can you post your css

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons.   I am using Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

Try like that:

```
<div class="font-weight-bold col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"> // use fullwidth for large, medium and small devices
  <span>Filter :</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

You can read more about [bootstrap grid system here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things here:

1) get rid of the `"form-control"`, add a class of your own and set its width using CSS

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="my-input" />
```

**CSS**

```
.my-input {
  width: 100px; // or the width you desire
}
```

2) Overwrite the CSS of the element inside the media query.

Somewhere in bootstrap CSS you have a selector (of "form-control") inside a media query which gives the input a smaller width. You can create your own media query and selector and overwrite it.

3) Sort of a combination of both. You can just add a class to the input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control my-input" />
```

and then add CSS according to the screen width.

It might not be that elegant - but you can also use `!important` on the width and then it won't be overwritten when the screen size changes.

Like:

```
.my-input {
  width: 100px !important; //again - not elegant, but will do the work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the **CSS** for input as:

```
input {
  width: calc(100% - 55px)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="font-weight-bold">
  <span>Filter :</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

55px is the width allotted for the label. The input will adjust itself as per the screen and the label width without using any bootstrap also.